# How can I put an if statement inside of a if-else if statement

Tags: java

I am trying to make a salary calculator that if the applicant is under 18, they cannot receive overtime, because in the state I am in the maximum allowed for minors is 18 hours. I have it set where you cannot earn overtime until you reach 40 hours. Is there anything I can do for this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SalaryV2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

//Declare and initialize variables
double totalSalary;
boolean isOvertime;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//Input
System.out.print("Please enter your name (first last): ");
String firstName = in.next();
String lastName = in.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
String customerAge = in.nextLine();
double age = Double.parseDouble(customerAge);

System.out.print("\nWhat is your hourly rate of pay: ");
String rateOfPay = in.nextLine();
double payRate = Double.parseDouble(rateOfPay);

System.out.print("\nHow many hours did you work: ");
String totalHoursWorked = in.nextLine();
double totalHours = Double.parseDouble(totalHoursWorked);
System.out.println();

    //Processing

 if(17 > age)
{
    isOvertime = false;
        totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
}
else if(totalHours > 40)
{
    if(totalHours > 40)
    {
        isOvertime = true;
        totalSalary = 40 * payRate + (totalHours - 40) * payRate * 1.5;
    }
    else
    {
        isOvertime = false;
        totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
    }
}
    

    
    

//Output
System.out.print("Employee Name: " + lastName + ", " + firstName\n);
System.out.print("Hours worked: " + totalHours);
System.out.println("\t\tOvertime: " + isOvertime +);
System.out.println("Salary: " + totalSalary);
```

}
}

Comment: If they state they're minor and enter 20 working hours, what's the expected output?

Comment: You ask how to put an `if` inside an `if-else`  and show code which does just that (even an `if-else` within an `if-else`). I do not get what answer you need.

Comment: The law is of course not the point of the question, but do I understand correctly that if a minor and a grown up both work the same long time, the minor must be paid less? I hope you (or I) have misunderstood something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep it simple, no need for else-if-if,

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SalaryV2{
public static void main(String[] args){

//Declare and initialize variables
double totalSalary= 0;
boolean isOvertime = false;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

//Input
System.out.print("Please enter your name (first last): ");
String firstName = in.next();
String lastName = in.nextLine();

System.out.print("Please enter your age: ");
String customerAge = in.nextLine();
double age = Double.parseDouble(customerAge);

System.out.print("\nWhat is your hourly rate of pay: ");
String rateOfPay = in.nextLine();
double payRate = Double.parseDouble(rateOfPay);

System.out.print("\nHow many hours did you work: ");
String totalHoursWorked = in.nextLine();
double totalHours = Double.parseDouble(totalHoursWorked);
System.out.println();

//Processing

if(age >= 18 && totalHours > 40) {
  isOvertime = true;
  totalSalary = 40 * payRate + (totalHours - 40) * payRate * 1.5;
}else{
  isOvertime = false;
  totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
}

//Output
System.out.print("Employee Name: " + lastName + ", " + firstName +'\n' );
System.out.print("Hours worked: " + totalHours + '\n');
System.out.println("Overtime: " + isOvertime );
System.out.println("Salary: " + totalSalary);

}}
```

With the following input STDIN
firstname lastname
19
10
42

Output :

```
$javac SalaryV2.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M SalaryV2
Please enter your name (first last): Please enter your age: 
What is your hourly rate of pay: 
How many hours did you work: 
Employee Name: lastname, firstname
Hours worked: 42.0
Overtime: true
Salary: 430.0
```

If under 18 STDIN

firstname lastname
17
10
42

Output :

```
$javac SalaryV2.java
$java -Xmx128M -Xms16M SalaryV2
Please enter your name (first last): Please enter your age: 
What is your hourly rate of pay: 
How many hours did you work: 
Employee Name:  lastname, firstname
Hours worked: 42.0
Overtime: false
Salary: 420.0
```

Checked by executing the above code.

Comment: You deserve the upvotes and have mine.

Comment: Thank you, let me try that really quick.

Comment: It worked, thank you so much!

Comment: Again Thank you. I actually didn't know you could put more than one condition in if statements. Just like Flacuchentxox cleared it up for me, you did too.

Comment: You are welcome, we share and learn. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are a minor you cannot get additional pay for any overtime you work (strange as that may seem).
If you have less than 40 hours you cannot get pay for overtime (everybody knows the weird  consequences of that...).

So you can only get paid for overtime if you are over 18 and have more than 40 hours.

```java
if((18 <= age) && (totalHours > 40))
{
    isOvertime = true;
    totalSalary = 40 * payRate + (totalHours - 40) * payRate * 1.5;
} else
{   
    isOvertime = false;
    totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
}
```

I.e. I do not see the need for nested `if`s.

Comment: I noticed my mistake while commenting on https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656707/7733418 But https://stackoverflow.com/a/69656693/7733418 directly did it right from the start AND provided proof via testing. Thanks for upvoting my answer everybody, but that one really deserves it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand very well your question, but here is something you can improve.

In the first if, you are not considering even 17 years old, you should put `if(17 >= age)` or `if(18 > age)`.

Then, in the else if you put the same condition as the if below, so what you should do is:

```
else if(totalHours > 40)
{
    isOvertime = true;
    totalSalary = 40 * payRate + (totalHours - 40) * payRate * 1.5;
}
else
{
    isOvertime = false;
    totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
}
```

And to make your code more efficient, you can put two conditions in one if.

```
if(18 > age && totalHours > 40)
{
    isOvertime = false;
    totalSalary = totalHours * payRate;
}
else
{
    isOvertime = true;
    totalSalary = 40 * payRate + (totalHours - 40) * payRate * 1.5;
}
```

*I didn't check if the code actually works, but it should be fine*

Comment: `if(18 > age && totalHours > 40)` If you are a minor AND worked long you get normal pay. If you are either a grown up or  worked shortly you get overtime. If you worked shortly the calculation means you get paid insufficiently. That is two things which probably are not intended.

Comment: Thank you, I understand, just where I live, which is what I have to go by, minors are not allowed to work over 18 hours a week and 6 days in a week, so average 3 hours a day. I hope you understand, but other wise I wouldn't have bothered with the minor stuff, no pun intended.

Comment: Again Thank you. I actually didn't know you could put more than one condition in if statements.